# Use Firebase connections properly for building a chat app

Tags: android, chat, firebase

I'm evaluating Firebase for building a chat app. And it's plan makes me concern: 10,000 concurrent connections/$1,499/month.

It seems to me that the chat app will have an always-on connection to Firebase, to receive incoming messages instantly. It means that if my app get 10,000 active installs on Android, then no matter whether they're opening the app or not, I will have to pay $1,499/a month.

Anyone know a solution for reducing concurrent connections to Firebase without impacting the perceived quality of the chat app? Thanks.

## Note

This is a chat app, and the perceived quality of the chat app is important. So the connection on Android is never released if the device has internet connection.

Comment: You could revert to polling, but that would essentially negate the advantages of using Firebase. How certain are you that you will reach that number of **concurrent** users? If it is just a fear/risk, I would recommend waiting for it to become a real problem. Having 10K concurrent chat users is a good problem to have. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Having 10k users or 10k downloads of your app does not equate to having 10k concurrent users all logged in and looking at your chat app at the same time.

A more accurate rule of thumb is 1 concurrent > 1200 monthly visits for the typical website or app (apps actually average even higher). For example, 50 concurrent connections equals roughly 50,000 visits a month, where 750 would be nearing a million visitors.

Most developers vastly overestimate the number of concurrent users they will have. As a data point, most web sites operate comfortably on the "free" Firebase plan most days. In fact, more than 99.5% of all of Firebases never hit the 50 concurrent limit.

So, long story short, 10k concurrents is more than enough for our self-serve customers and once you've approached 12 million users, well, hopefully an enterprise option will be appealing by that point.

Comment: It's true for a web app scenario. But I'm talking about an Android app. And it's a chat app. Our company has only 25 people (only 5 are developers), and although the app hasn't released yet, but the peak concurrents is 20. I would disagree if 50 concurrent connections could handle 50,000 visits in this case.

Comment: For android and iOS apps, it's actually even more liberal, coming closer to 1400 per concurrent. People use apps in shorter bursts than they sit at the compy. There are, of course, exception and your app could be one, but 20 concurrents doesn't account for much--that could be entirely forge connections, back end services, and dev users. Make sure you have some solid metrics before worrying yourself too much here.

Comment: in case the user isn't online, can Firebase send push notifications to them? If not, do you have any suggestions on doing that?

Comment: These calculations are valid for request/response scenario (like HTTP). But not for persistent connection scenario (like Websocket or plain TCP, usually used in chat apps). I don't know exact numbers, but they are not as big as monthly visits for a typical req/res scenario (web-site). For req/res scenario if user uses an app for 30min/day, the time that app will spent sending a request or waiting for a response will be like 10s in total (that's why the ratio of monthly visits to concurrent connections is so big), but for chat-app it will be.. well.. 30min... so the ratio is much less.